# Simulated iphone app quits, whenever I turned on debugging

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I always build my app choosing with 'Build and run' (not 'build and debug'). While the app running smoothly I opt to put a breakpoint over a line. When I do this the simulated application suddenly quits  with a message 'Loading debugger..,Debugging terminated'. 
...Actually, this happens only on putting breakpoint on first time.

Any help, please.

---

Xcode consol log..

Session started at 2010-03-31 20:54:59 +0530.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1461.2) (Fri Mar  5 04:43:10 UTC 2010)
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".A0:0

..
Attaching to process 10016.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""XXX.mm":247" resolved
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Loading program into debugger…
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""XXX":247" resolved
kill

consol app log....

31/03/10 8:55:02 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[94]
   (UIKitApplication:com.xxxx.yyyyy[0x25ab][10016]) Exited: Killed
31/03/10 8:55:02 PM SpringBoard[10014]  Application 'XXXXXX' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
31/03/10 8:55:02 PM SpringBoard[10014]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. 
Telephony state may be incorrect.

Comment: what is your stacktrace?

Comment: Before even debugging is started, App quits silently ): I am appending 'xcode console log' and console app log for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a second monitor connected to your development machine ? If so, try unplugging it and see if that helps. Seriously: http://support.appcelerator.net/discussions/support/572-iphone-simulator-shows-no-windows

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar experience, rebuilding your application will fix the issue.

If it is still crashing try to crack the crash report http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

There is similar topic discussed in another forum go through this http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=474267

Comment: Is your app crashing on device also.

Comment: Ya.. Also note, this happens randomly .Some time it works smoothly.